# Difference not shown in pull request after manual revert in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I encountered an issue where a particular change did not appear in the pull request diff on Bitbucket.

There are four branches involved: my-feature-branch, develop, staging-branch, and feature-xyz (handled by a different team member). Other team members push their completed features into staging-branch to ensure everything works well before merging into develop.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I made changes in my-feature-branch.
2. I pulled the changes from staging-branch, which included changes from feature-xyz because it had already been merged into staging-branch.
3. Upon reviewing the differences in the pull request, I found an unrelated change from a different branch that I needed to revert. Let's call it the "xyz" change from branch feature-xyz. I manually reverted the “xyz” code and committed the change.
4. Later, the feature-xyz branch, on which another team member was working, got merged into develop.
5. I raised a pull request to merge my-feature-branch, which had the "xyz" change reverted, into develop.
6. However, the pull request did not show the reversal of the "xyz" change in the difference.

I was expecting the pull request to display that my-feature-branch did not have the "xyz" change since develop already contained the change merged from feature-xyz. Sadly, the reverted change got merged into develop. But fortunately, another team member noticed that the "xyz" change had been inadvertently reverted as they were expecting this update in the latest release.

I'm trying to understand why this happened and why Bitbucket failed to display the difference in the pull request. From what I understand, Git will compare the commit history of my source branch and target branch and then shows the differences. Considering this, my source branch did have the commit (code reversal) in its commit history but still did not get picked up.

Comment: I don't know what it means (and why) Gitbucket failed to display the difference in the pull request. But aside from that, what you describe is totally expected behavior. When a branch (feature-xyz) is merged into two others (my-feature-branch and develop), then one of the branches makes another change (revert-xyz), then a later merge of the two branches *of course* contains the additional change. It is completely irrelevant that the change happens to be the reversal of some work in a common predecessor.

Comment: sure, I understand the reversal or any change for that matter will be part of the pull request. My concern is why it DID NOT show up in the diff in the UI which caused me to merge incorrect code. @j6t

Comment: Can you create an ascii-art chart of the commits involved? So that we can have a clearer picture of what happened?... _or_ a detailed list of git commands that we can follow to understand? Given that it's 4 branches involved, getting to see how they relate to each other will help a lot instead of making assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure to have understood your question:

```
*--*--X--a--b--c--d--e--f--g--h <- develop
       \
        1--bad--2--revert--3 <- my-feature-branch
```

First point :
the diff that is displayed in the Merge Request view is not the diff *between the two branches*, it is the diff between the candidate branch (`my-feature-branch`) and the *fork point* between that branch and the target branch (commit `X` in the diagram above).

*note*: this "fork point" is also called the merge-base

Now, if the history of your branch contains a change followed by its revert, then ultimately this change is not in `my-feature-branch` (in its topmost commit).

---

If your question was "if the change ended up on `develop`, why can't I see it in my merge request ?" :

- this change is *not* part of the differences between `X` and `my-feature-branch`, it appeared on `develop` *after* `X`
- it should have been visible in the merge request opened for `feature-xyz`

Comment: The feature-xyz which had the "xyz" code got merged into Develop first. The my-feature branch had got the "xyz" code when it pulled changes from the staging-branch [because feature-xyz was merged into staging-branch]. Now, I reverted the latest code to old code in my-feature and raised the PR to merge it into develop. Also, I could find the commit for "code reversal" in the 'my-feature' branch. In this case, I should have seen that my-feature branch contained the old code. What I am puzzled about is that I didn't find that diff in the PR [my-feature > develop] raised.

Comment: you can check `git log --oneline --graph develop my-feature` and see if you make sense of what branch contains what commit.